# best font(s) for tech blog

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

I am writing a tech blog, with regular prose paragraphs interspersed with short code fragments. I have the feeling the default font for the prose paragraphs is something old and boring like Times New Roman. It makes the paragraphs look like a textbook from the 1950s. Can you suggest one or more fonts that would liven up, and lighten up, my paragraphs?

Comment: Hi Argent, could you please [edit] you question with some more details. It's hard to make recommendations without either seeing the current design and/or having some clear requirements on what the font needs to be

Comment: This is a question about aesthetics, not about code,  symbolic logic, or circuit design.  Unclear how to make it more specific. When you're eating soup you use a spoon, not a fork and knife.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Raleway](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Raleway) is a good font but I must say that thinner fonts are better. [Try looking for those on Google Fonts.](https://fonts.google.com/?thickness=1)